# How to run a Stored Procedure as Sysadmin?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, xp-cmdshell

I don't want to grant the user Sysadmin role.
Is there any way to run a specific stored procedure as Sysadmin or as a user that is sysadmin?
The stored procedure is in MSSQL 2005 and has xp_cmdshell 
Below is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procExcelQuotebyItem] 
(
    @OrderNumber INT
)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE @Cmd varchar(1000)
DECLARE @fn varchar(500)
DECLARE @provider varchar(100)
DECLARE @ExcelString varchar(100)

--  New File Name to be created
SET @fn = 'D:\Pre-Manufacturing\Excel\QuotebyItem.xls'

/*Cleanup*/

SET @Cmd = 'DEL ' + @fn
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd, no_output

--  FileCopy command string formation
SET @Cmd = 'Copy D:\Pre-Manufacturing\Excel\QuotebyItemTemplate.xls ' + @fn

--  FileCopy command execution through Shell Command
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd, NO_OUTPUT

--  Mentioning the excel destination filename
SET @provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
SET @ExcelString = 'Excel 8.0;Database=' + @fn

EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:L2]'') 
SELECT [ITEMNUMBER],'''',[ITEM_DESCRIPTION],[CASEPACK],[UNIT PRICE],[CASE PRICE],[WEIGHT],[CUBE],[CASE DIMS],[UPC],[CASE UPC],[Q Comments] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + '''')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo
WITH EXECUTE AS 'USER_ID_with_sysadmin_rights'
AS
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Test code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test1
WITH EXECUTE AS 'CORP\jbooth'
AS
select user_name()
GO
EXEC test1
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.test1
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
select user_name()
GO
EXEC test1
```

Additional info for gettting XP_CMDSHELL to work in SQL 2005

[SQL 2005 XP_CMDSHELL](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/61804/xp-cmdshell-permission-denied-SQL-2005)

Comment: I added a little test example, however I do not have SQL 2005 installed, just 2008.   I did use this in version 2005, so it should work fine...

Comment: As far as I remembered an object in a user database can't be given `EXEC AS ` a server role. Have you managed to get `xp_cmdshell ` to run?

Comment: Could be some permission issue like that, it has been a while since I've used SQL 2005 and I can see the security implications. Worst case scenario, I guess he would need to create a user with the needed rights and assign the procedure to that user instead. I think his question is asking for that, a user that has SysAdmin rights.. (I'll modify the example to make it clearer) Thanks for the heads-up....

Comment: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procExcelQuotebyItem, Line 49
Cannot execute as the user 'sysadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: I changed the EXECUTE AS 'domain\user' and it gave the following error: `Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.`  AND:  `Msg 15274, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.`

Comment: What permissions does the user need to have? The particular user I tried had the sysadmin server role.

Comment: Try GRANT EXECUTE rights to that procedure for the user.   I remember that XP_ procedure have some security concerns, but I think GRANT EXECUTE should do it for you...

Comment: EXECUTE AS 'domain\user' works and the xp_cmdshell runs, but now I get the following error when it tries to execute the INSERT INTO OPENROWSET: `Msg 15274, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.`

Comment: I would suggest creating a new question, I am very rusty on the security model of SQL 2005 and I would suggest you open that particular question up to the entire Stack Overflow community for a good answer...    Sorry

Comment: Thanks Sparky. Where would I place the GRANT EXECUTE at? `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procExcelQuotebyItem] 
(
    @OrderNumber INT
)
GRANT EXECUTE AS 'USer without permission' AS
`?

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374436/t-sql-create-user-and-grant-execute-on-permission-for-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0):

I removed EXECUTE AS and added `EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'Corporate\HelenS', 'sysadmin';` Works! Then I drop the role `EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'Corporate\HelenS', 'sysadmin'`

Comment: I thought that in order to add a server role member, the user calling the stored procedure has to be a db_owner and sys_admin, in which case, your sp should already work for that user.

Comment: This creates a huge potential security hole, and should not be an accepted answer.