# How to add SQL LocalDB permissions

Tags: sql, authentication, database-permissions, localdb

I.. "accidentally" removed my database permissions for my windows login to localdb

Any idea how to give permissions back to that database?

Comment: You need some account has the permission, like sa account to add your account back to your localDB

Answer (score -4):

Check the following:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx

[t-sql create user and grant execute on permission for stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374436/t-sql-create-user-and-grant-execute-on-permission-for-stored-procedures#)